# Using LINQ to compare strings alphabetically

Tags: c#, linq

I have a collection of objects. Each object has a string property. I'm trying to get a list of those objects where the string is alphabetically before or after a specified string.

Here's an example of what I mean:
I have four objects with string properties of `apple`, `banana`, `carrot`, and `dirt`. The specified string I use is `c`. I want to use LINQ to return the first two objects with string properties of `apple` and `banana`. As a bonus, the ability to include `carrot` would be nice as well in the same statement rather than use a separate LINQ query for `==`.

Here's what I've tried (and variations of it):

```
var query = from feature in features
            where String.Compare(feature.ColumnValues[selectedField], stringToCompare, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) < 0
            select feature;
```

Where `features` is my collection.

This isn't returning the correct objects though. It's returning objects that come both before and after alphabetically.

Edit: Can't post the full collection since it's thousand of objects, but the strings being compared to are all locations. For example, `In US`, `Maryland`, `Near Texas`, etc.

A `Feature` object has a `Dictionary<string, string>` called `ColumnValues`. The `Key` value, which is my `selectedField` is `LOCATION`. The `Value` for that `Key` is what I'm comparing my `stringToCompare` to, for each `Feature`.

Edit 2: The problem seemed to be with casing.

Comment: _This isn't returning the correct objects though._ what is it returning?

Comment: Try using a Sorted Dictionary.

Comment: Updated my answer. If there is a space in a string, does that somehow put it lower in the order? For instance, I have a string `In US` that is returned in the query when I'm comparing it to "B".

Comment: This code works fine for me with the "apple", "banana", "carrot", "dirt" test data. It returns "apple", "banana" for < 0 and "carrot", "dirt" for > 0 comparing with "c". However, I've tested it with a list of strings, not your `feature` objects. Mind providing a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: "In US" should be `>` "B". The comparison will be done character by character, so the space has no effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried the code you have provided above.You can use the following for filtering and sorting list:

```
    public class Feature
    {

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string ColumnValues { get; set; }
    }

  var features = new List<Feature> { new Feature {Id=1,ColumnValues="carrot" } ,
                 new Feature {Id=1,ColumnValues="dirt" },
                  new Feature {Id=1,ColumnValues="banana" }, new Feature {Id=1,ColumnValues="apple" }
            };

  string strToComapre = "c";
  int lenOfString = 1;

 var query=(from feature in features
                  where String.CompareOrdinal(feature.ColumnValues, 0, strToComapre, 0, lenOfString) <= 0
         select feature).OrderBy(x => x.ColumnValues);
```

this is returning the values apple,banana and carrot.I have take ColumnValues fields as the field having the string to compare.As there can be any number of characters in the original string so OrdinalComparison is right approach here.

In this example I have taken the variable ***lenOfString***  as "1" but you can define this appropriately depending upon the length of the string.Since here length is "1"( we are comparing "c"), I have set the length as "1".

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The code works for the small list of Features, but not with the thousands of items I'm working with. I updated my post to hopefully give a better example of the objects I'm working with. I have no idea why it's not working, since it works fine with a shorter list of the same values.